# iOS 8 glitch effecting window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios8

I've got some very simple code:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            $("#foo").show(); $("#foo2").hide();
        } else if ($(window).width() > 501) {
            $("#foo2").show(); $("#foo").hide();
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

All was working fine on desktop (all major browsers) and mobile (as many as I could test), till iOS 8 came out. Now when a users scrolls in Safari the javascript falls back to 'else if', creating 'foo2' and hiding 'foo' despite the browser not resizing. This is for a menu, as such the menu closes if the user scrolls which shouldn't be happening.

If I remove the window resize function all works as it should, however the menu doesn't update in real time if the user resizes the browser window.

Is there an alternative to window resize I can use to achieve the same effect?

Comment: what kind of break point is 500px?

Comment: The width is needed for a particular client requirement. In any case you can consider it an X variable. It happens on multiple break points.

Answer (score 1):

...so, considering I get the problem as you describe it, you can avoid javascript and do it using pure css and media queries:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
  #foo {
    display:block;
  }
  #foo2 {
    display:none;
  }
}
@media (min-width:501px) {
  #foo2 {
    display:block;
  }
  #foo {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

**edit:** ..this will definately have nothing to do with scrolling and will certainly be faster and cleaner

Comment: Yes indeed it would, but my code is simplified to demo this problem. There are other reasons JS was deployed in this case. It's just clicked that when a user browses in iOS 8 a pop up box appears from the bottom of safari (bookmark page/ send link etc) & the URL box at the top changes shape. This must be triggering the window resize function creating the weird behaviour. So now all I need to know is how to use a window resize function that only looks at the x axis..

Comment: hmm, have you tried using the meta viewport tag to see if it makes any difference? I am at work and don't have access to my ios devices now, but please try this and see if the resize is still triggered: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"/>

Comment: Good idea, but no unfortunately it didn't work..or at least not better than '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">'which I was already using.

Comment: what amazes me is that 500px breakpoint. Are you using the iphone horizontally?

Comment: Nah, it's actually a desktop requirement. A special menu is needed for call center staff so they can have multiple windows open at once. It's a long story. If I find a simple answer I'll report back, otherwise a big rework is in the works.

Comment: dan, the reason I am asking is only because I find the breakpoint strange to be triggered on an iphone unless it's in landscape mode. The actual iphone's width on websites taking the pixel-ratio into account is 320px so it shouldn't use the 'else if' clause of > 501px

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but I'd store the width of the window on load and then check against that on the resize to ensure an actual resize took place horizontally. That would ensure that the code only fired when the browser changed size on the x axis.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    if (windowWidth !== $(window).width())
    {
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        // rest of your code goes here
    }
});
```

Remember that the resize event could fire quite a lot while someone is resizing, so you may want to limit the whole thing using setInterval, but that's a separate discussion.